# How to export a MongoDB database to JSON?

Tags: json, mongodb

It is possible to export a mongodb database to json on windows?
I've already searched and the only thing that I find is to export collections. Is that the only way?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example for a collection

```
mongoexport --collection=mycollection --db=mydb --out=myoutput.json
```

Use `mongodump` for the whole database

```
mongodump -d mydb -o output.json
```

Comment: But that only export a collection, not the entire database, right?

Comment: See now that you edited the answer, I'll try that!  Thank you!

Comment: Check out the edit! Hope that works for you. That format should work on Linux.

Comment: Fantastic! Glad to hear it!